# My App Crashes With List Radio Button

Tags: android, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

My application crashes when I click on a radio button. 
The radio Buttons are generated Dynamically. But, when I refer to that button it crashes.

The crash occurs Here when the snackbar is shown. I believe when 
 when I call the method getText for the selected Button.

How can I fix it ?

Here is my code:

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    String[] filename = getApplicationContext().fileList();

    addRadioButtons(filename.length, filename);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            RadioGroup rd = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.file_radio_group);
            int id_Btn = rd.getCheckedRadioButtonId() ;
            RadioButton selectedRB = (RadioButton) findViewById(id_Btn) ;

            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action "+selectedRB.getText().toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });



}
public void addRadioButtons(int number,String[] filenames) {

    for (int row = 0; row < 1; row++) {
        RadioGroup ll = new RadioGroup(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
            RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);
            rdbtn.setId((row * 2) + i);
            rdbtn.setText(filenames[i-1]);
            //rdbtn.setText("Radio " + rdbtn.getId());
            rdbtn.setTextSize(25);
            ll.addView(rdbtn);
        }
        ((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.file_radio_group)).addView(ll);
    }
}
}
```

Here is my Logcat

```
 11-01 19:04:26.460 6743-6743/alahdal.amjad.newloginproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: alahdal.amjad.newloginproject, PID: 6743
 java.lang.NullPointerExceptionat 
 alahdal.amjad.newloginproject.ListActivity$1.onClick(ListActivity.java:39)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)     atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Anyways, I dont' know why it crashes. Please Help

Comment: The steps to solving this are 1. reading the stack trace (Logcat, see https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html#running for more information on setting it up and using it) to see what the actual Exception is that caused the failure, possibly in combination with 2. stepping through the code in debug mode and using breakpoints to determine where it's crashing and what would be causing that

Comment: Can you show the error log please.

Comment: I pasted it in the question. anyways, I checked again, the Problem when I call the method getText.to_String

Comment: Maybe your `selectedRB` is null?

Comment: you got to make sure it's not null

Comment: It's Null. THank You guys. But, How can I refer to the clicked button ???????

Comment: Thank You guys. I fixed it by making ll in the method addRadioButton private and to be seen in the entire class

Comment: will you paste your xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RadioGroup ll; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
String[] filename = getApplicationContext().fileList();

addRadioButtons(filename.length, filename);

FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        RadioGroup rd = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.file_radio_group);
        int id_Btn = rd.getCheckedRadioButtonId() ;
        RadioButton selectedRB = (RadioButton) findViewById(id_Btn) ;

        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action "+selectedRB.getText().toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
    }
});



}


  public void addRadioButtons(int number,String[] filenames) {

for (int row = 0; row < 1; row++) {
    ll = new RadioGroup(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
        RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);
        rdbtn.setId((row * 2) + i);
        rdbtn.setText(filenames[i-1]);
        //rdbtn.setText("Radio " + rdbtn.getId());
        rdbtn.setTextSize(25);
        ll.addView(rdbtn);
    }
    ((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.file_radio_group)).addView(ll);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go, I'm not clear with your requirements but don't get the idea of adding another radio group to already one in xml. Here is corrected version working fine.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.file_radio_group);
    String[] filename = getApplicationContext().fileList();
    addRadioButtons(radioGroup, filename.length, filename);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int id_Btn = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            for (int count = 0; count < radioGroup.getChildCount(); count++) {
                if (radioGroup.getChildAt(count).getId() == id_Btn) {
                    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(count);
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action " + radioButton.getText().toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

public void addRadioButtons(RadioGroup radioGroup, int number, String[] filenames) {
    radioGroup.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
        RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);
        rdbtn.setId((i * 2) + i);
        rdbtn.setText(filenames[i - 1]);
        rdbtn.setTextSize(25);
        radioGroup.addView(rdbtn);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If no radio button is selected 
`rd.getCheckedRadioButtonId()`
will return -1 and that would not be any view's id so `findViewById` cannot find a view.

Check for -1 before using `id_Btn` to find views.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    RadioGroup rd = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.file_radio_group);
    int id_Btn = rd.getCheckedRadioButtonId() ;
    if (id_Btn != -1) {
        RadioButton selectedRB = (RadioButton) findViewById(id_Btn) ;
    } else {
        //Handle case if no button is selected
    }

    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action "+selectedRB.getText().toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
    }
```